# Pet bonus chance for twins; when to assign the pet?

Tags: fallout-shelter

OK, so I have Pango (the Dalmation pet that gives a 75% bonus chance to having twins) and I've used it a fair amount to rapidly increase my vault's population.

However, when do I assign Pango to a dweller to increase that chance? Is it just when they are pregnant? Is it at conception? If it's assigned to the father at conception does that count? Does it only take it into account at birth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know (since I had Pongo too), **it applies only when it is assigned to the mother.** *The bonus applies even if you assign it just before birth.*

Comment: OK from experience, that makes sense. And FYI, presumably to avoid a legal fight with Disney, the dog is specifically called p**a**ngo.